# Read property file values with environment variables

Tags: java, properties

I have a property file such like this

```
human.name=${HUMAN_NAME:defaultName}
human.age=${HUMAN_AGE}
human.def=Value
```

I need to read it on runtime in java without the spring framework.
Is there a method how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use regular expressions. It helps find necessary value. [About regex in Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: You might use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html with combination of `System.getenv()` (but commons-text uses `${VAR:-defaultValue}`, just like BASH, so you have to change format)